# Strategies to reduce the number of instantiated objects

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, memory-management

Early in our project we created a Locale class which contains a string such as "en-US" from which we can derive the country and language and some other info.

The issue we are facing right now is that we are creating way too many Locale objects. Those objects are used pretty much everywhere as parameters or Dictionary/HashSet keys. After doing some profiling, we realized that we spend way too much time creating those Locale objects.

Knowing that we have a finite set of locales and that those objects are immutable, what pattern would you propose to keep to the minimum the number of object created?

Comment: Just as an aside to the given answers (which are fine), be sure to account for thread-safe access if applicable.  For example, using a `Dictionary` to cache the entries will inherently not be thread safe (unless perhaps you can guarantee that the cache will be prebuilt before any reads).  I'm not sure if that's an issue for you, but given you said that you're using them "everywhere" and even measuring a non-trivial processing time handling them, I figured it could be applicable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) to create objects by some index and return cached instances (assuming your objects are immutable, otherwise returning shared copy would be dangerous).

I.e. follow [CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540) implementation which have factory methods that return instance by one of the keys.

```
public static CultureInfo GetCultureInfo(string name)
```

> Retrieves a cached, read-only instance of a culture by using the specified culture name.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is caching.  There are several ways to implement it, but the general idea is to have some structure that stores all of the previously created locals, and rather than making a new one, you search through that collection first.

One option for you is to create a `Dictionary<string, Locale>`.  The string would be the string like "en-US".  Each time you want to create a new `Locale` first check if it's in the `Dictionary`.  If it is, just return it.  if not, actually make a new one and put it in the `Dictionary`.

```
public static class LocaleFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Locale> cache = new Dictionary<string, Locale>();

    public static Locale GetLocal(string localeString)
    {
        Locale output;
        if (cache.TryGetValue(localeString, out output))
        {
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            output = new Locale(localeString);
            //do other creation stuff for the Locale
            cache.Add(localeString, output);
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like that:

```
class Locale {
    static Locale en;
    static Locale de;
    ...
    static Locale getLocale(string local){
      //checking if the wanted local already exists and return it or instance it
    }
};
```

like a singleton but a bit different